System BroadcastReceiver is not working for diffrent app variant in Android
I am using a system (PHONE_STATE) broadcast. It is working fine in my default veriant but when I switch to another one where I changed the applicationId by using applicationIdSuffix. The system broadcast (PHONE_STATE) is not working for the changed flavor! how to resolve this?
I have registered the broadcast in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

       <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.PhoneCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


To resolve the issue with the PHONE_STATE broadcast not working in a flavor with a different applicationId:

Add the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


Register the broadcast receiver programmatically in your Application class:

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String packageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(new PhoneStateReceiver(), filter, packageName);
    }
}

This ensures the receiver is registered correctly for each flavor. Verify the applicationId in your BuildConfig class matches the package name in your manifest file. Debug the registration process if issues persist.

The arguments do not match in the registerReceiver() method you provided by giving the packageName as an argument! @DST
